# Is there an easy way to collect LatLng coordinates as geojson?

Tags: csv, leaflet, data-visualization, openstreetmap, geojson

I have a set of information as a csv-file that I want to bind in several pop-ups using Leaflet.js. For that I need to collect hundereds of city-coordinates mentioned in the csv-file.

During my research I found [OSM Boundaries](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/) what makes collecting geojson-data quite easy. But the problem with OSM boundaries is that it only contains geometry as MultiPolygons.

In my case I'm searching for a single pair `LatLng` coordinates like from the citycenter or so.

[geojson.io](http://geojson.io) is another simple tool to collect geojson. I can search for the cities but need to set a marker on the map by myself. That seems quite uncomfortable to me.

I know that Open Street Map offers all the information I need, I just don't no how to export/collect them properly.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Sounds like your issue may not be very clear. What type of information do you have in your CSV file, and why do you need to retrieve new information from an external service? Do you mean you have only city names in your CSV, and you need to retrieve their centroid lat/lng coordinates?

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. Yes, the CSV file has specific information on every city like the city name, population, ... and I'm searching for an easy method to place the specific information on the map as popup for example. I thought that it would be the best way to collect all the coordinates as geojson and then merging them with the CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound to be looking for **geocoding** functionality, i.e. finding the lat-lng coordinates of your places by city name.

Please have a look at [Leaflet geocoding plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding). With most of them, you can use them programmatically, instead of manually entering the city name. Check out each one API.

Note that your result may still need some manual clean up, as geocoding often gives you several matching places.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a set of information as a csv-file that I want to bind in several pop-ups using Leaflet.js.

You don't need GeoJSON at all. Simply load the CSV as a text string, parse it, iterate through the rows, and instantiate Leaflet markers as needed.